# Error when cordova launch my app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a big problem. I execute the comand ionic cordova run android and all is OK. The build is success, however, when the app is launching, the app throw a message`'Unfortunately, app has stopped.'`
I have tried to see the logcat with adb locgat and the error is that:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process
Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
```

I have never seen that error before and my app is the same, i have changed anything.
Please, could someone help me? Thank you.

*The command `ionic serve` works fine.

Comment: You are using anything related to firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure to Download your Firebase configuration files, GoogleService-Info.plist for ios and google-services.json for android, and place them in the root folder of your cordova project

```
- My Project/
    platforms/
    plugins/
    www/
    config.xml
    google-services.json       <--
    GoogleService-Info.plist   <--
    ...
```

See https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592 for details how to download the files from firebase.

**Issue is resolved with this [link](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/142). Below is the extract from that link**

> Follow this steps.
>
> Inside the platforms folder, android/src/{package
>   name}/MainActivity.java
>
> Import the firebase library,
>
> import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp; Inside the oncreate method,
>   below super.oncreate(savedinstancestate),
>
> Add FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
>
> Last step,
>
> Inside the platforms folder, android/res/values/string.xml,
>
> Add ***
>
> *** can be found in the googleservice.json file "client": [ { "client_info": { "mobilesdk_app_id": this value

Comment: Yes, i have the google-service.json in my root folder. All work fine but, suddenly, i had this error and i don't know how solve it. I have tried downgrade, update, reinstall the cordova platform, reinstall node_modules, reinstall de plugins... but i dont find the solution :(